# How can I override an HTML "rules" attribute using CSS?

Tags: html, css, dita, dita-ot

The DITA Open Toolkit automatically inflicts some inline table attributes when one publishes to HTML, including frame="border" and rules="all".

I need to override this "rules" attribute using CSS styles for cells, and while I can get the desired result in IE and Chrome, Firefox puts solid black gridlines in the table and refuses to budge on the matter.

Obviously I can't edit the HTML, company policy is to not edit the XSLT, so how can I remove these gridlines using CSS alone?

I've tried various cunning combinations of border-xxxxxx styles and given them !important declarations to no effect.

The HTML says...

```
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" frame="border" border="1" rules="all">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="cellrowborder">Type </th>
      <th class="cellrowborder">Comment </th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cellrowborder">Caution </td>
      <td class="cellrowborder">Think twice. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cellrowborder">Attention </td>
      <td class="cellrowborder">Be careful. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cellrowborder">Danger </td>
      <td class="cellrowborder" >Be scared. Be very scared. </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS says

```
table {border: 1px solid black;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 font-size: 9pt;
 margin-top: 1em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 padding: 4px;}

tr {border: none;}

.cellrowborder {border: none;}
```

So while it looks as I'd expect in IE, it doesn't in Firefox UNLESS I remove those frame/border/rules attributes in the HTML. Which I can't in production.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's remove attribute on document load to remove the old attributes all together.

api.jquery.com/removeAttr

Answer (score 2):

I've had a quick play with `<table frame="border" rules="all">`. The key seems to be to override it with another border, for example:

```
table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    td {
        border: 1px solid silver;
    }
```

It's not ideal if you need to remove the border altogether, but I guess you could match the `border-color` to the page background?

Answer (score 1):

`border-color` seems to apply.

Comment: Please give an example of it working in Firefox. This doesn't in FF10 - http://jsfiddle.net/ajcw/GYYHb/

Comment: So `border-color` works in Firefox when applied to the table cells, but not the table itself.

Comment: So it would seem, arguably because the rules were not actually applied to the table, but its cells.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using FireBug Inspect Element can help you detect the CSS property and allow you to target it in Firefox ([instructions here](http://justaddwater.dk/wp-content/uploads/2007/04/firebug-css-tip-start-html-inspector.png)).

Can you post an example of the code?